# how to go back root view controller from recursive view controller(fourth)

Tags: ios

```
class FourthViewController : UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var previousLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var backButton: UIButton!

    var delegate: FourthToFirst?
    var label = ""

    // MARK: - Lifecycle method
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        previousLabel.text = label
        let fourthViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FourthViewController") as? FourthViewController
        navigationController?.pushViewController(fourthViewController!, animated: true)
    }

    // MARK: - IBAction
    @IBAction func backToFirst(_ sender: Any) {
        navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    }
```

Actually I am in fourthviewController it was going recursively(i.e pushing the fourthViewcontroller again and again, nonstop)

if I pressed back button in the controller I have to go back(i.e firstviewcontroller)

problem is:

In my code it was going (i.e non stop)

I can't press the back button to go back(i.e firstviewcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

`navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)` instead of `navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)` could be what's you need mate. (Based on what's you just edited)

Comment: Actually u misunderstand my question. I edited my question ,

Comment: please check it out

Comment: `navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)` instead of `navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)` could be what's you need mate.